# Limiting the number of rows imported into Excel from a large CSV file

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I have a large CSV file with approximately 70,000,000 rows. I have read how to import it into Excel as a data model and then pivot table [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2017/02/12/loading-csvtext-files-with-more-than-a-million-rows-into-excel/). Is there a way in Excel to just load a certain number of rows directly into a sheet, akin to SQLs [TOP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql)?

Comment: You'll most likely need some VBA with an inputbox() asking you how many to import, then use FileSystemObject to read the data in from the .CSV. This might get you started https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719342/how-to-read-lines-from-a-text-file-one-by-one-with-power-point-vba-code

Comment: how are you importing it into excel ?

Comment: @PeterH I'm not, it's too big, hence the question.

Comment: @dumbledad apologies I miss read your question, I will look into this now, you should be able to truncate data in the power query editor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have only tried this with a CSV that is way smaller than 70 mill rows.

Go to data - get data, choose your CSV.

[image]

Click on the EDIT button to load it into power query editor.
Under the Add Column Head add an index column.

[image]

Then filter on this column, using number less than, and choose your desired number of ROWS.

[image]

Return to the Home tab, and click close and load.

[image]

AS I say I have never used this with a CSV of that size so let me know how you get on.

Comment: It worked :) And was even easier in the version of Excel I'm using. Instead of 'edit' I get 'transform data' and then there's a drop-down called 'keep rows' and one of the options under that is to specify the number of rows to keep. Perfect

Comment: glad it worked for, hate to think what a 70 million row data set would be like to work with

Answer (score 0):

Check out [TextQ](https://geosystemsdev.com/products/textq/) (disclaimer - I'm its developer). It can import a big CSV file and allows to query and filter it via a UI Query Builder or SQL (select, join, group by, etc). The UI Builder can convert to SQL with a click.

Query results can be exported to CSV.

You can get it from the [Mac App Store](https://apps.apple.com/au/app/textq/id1571423170) or Microsoft Store (soon).